# Как при создании одного объекта привязать к нему другой по id?

Tags: java, spring, rest, dto, mapper

Есть класс UserDTO и класс CarDTO

```java
public class UserDTO{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
//еще поля, геттеры сеттеры}

public class CarDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String color;
////еще поля, геттеры сеттеры}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при создании пользователя, машину к нему можно было привязать по id? То есть, чтобы не заполнять всю carDTO, а указать уже существующий айдишник конкретной машины? Метод на создание юзера в сервисе и контроллере ниже

```java
//@Service
    public long create(UserDTO us) {
        us.setId(null);
        User user = repository.save(userMapper.map(us));
        return user.getId();
//@Controller
 @PostMapping
    public Long createUser(@RequestBody UserDTO user){
        return userService.create(user);}
    }
```

Маппер

```java
  public User map(UserDTO u) {
        User us=new User;
        if(u!=null){
        us.setId(dto.getId());
        book.setName(dto.getName());
        return us;
    }
```

Comment: вариант создать в UserDTO поле carId вам не подходит?

Comment: мне подходит любой вариант, не могу придумать как изменить контроллер и сервис, чтобы при сохранении пользователя мне вводить только ид машины

Comment: можно код контролера и сервиса?

Comment: в теме написан метод контроллера на создание, сейчас переделываю на что-то подобное  @PostMapping("/{idCar}")
    public UserDTO createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO user, @PathVariable(value = "idCar") Long idCar){
        carService.findById(idCar);
        return  ;
    } , связь User - Car (многие к одному), одной машиной могут пользоваться несколько человек

Answer (score 0):

Сделать внешний ключ с id автомобиля для таблицы пользователей.

```
public class UserDTO{
private Long id;
private String name;
//внешний ключ
private Long car_id;
```

Посмотрите как это сделать [тут](https://easyjava.ru/data/jpa/jpa-i-svyazi-mezhdu-obektami/)

Comment: я уже сделал связи, у меня нет понимания, как изменить контроллер и сервис, чтобы мне вводить только ид машины при заполнении пользователя и как все это сохранять

Comment: @Fonetty так можете в маппере это поле заполнять `us.setCar(carRepository.findById(u.getCar_id()))`, или эту строчку перенести в сервис

Comment: если не сложно, напишите как должен выглядеть контроллер

Comment: @Fonetty 
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
public class UserController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    @GetMapping()
    public List<DAOUser> findAll(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") DAOUser user) {
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }`